# How to implement assert in Perl?

Tags: perl, eval, assert

When trying to implement C's `assert()` macro in Perl, there is some fundamental problem. Consider this code first:

```
sub assert($$) {
   my ($assertion, $failure_msg) = @_;
   die $failure_msg unless $assertion;
}

# ...
assert($boolean, $message);
```

While this works, it's not like C: In C I'd write `assert($foo <= $bar)`, but with this implementation I'd have to write `assert($foo <= $bar, '$foo <= $bar')`, i.e. *repeat* the condition as string.

Now  I wonder how to implement this *efficiently*. The easy variant seems to pass the string to `assert()` and use `eval` to evaluate the string, but you can't access the variables when evaluating eval. Even if it would work, it would be quite inefficient as the condition is parsed and evaluated each time.

When passing the expression, I have no idea how to make a string from it, especially as it's evaluated already.

Another variant using `assert(sub { $condition })` where it's likely easier to make a string from the code ref, is considered too ugly.

The construct `assert(sub { (eval $_[0], $_[0]) }->("condition"));` with

```
sub assert($)
{
    die "Assertion failed: $_[1]\n" unless $_[0];
}
```

would do, but is ugly to call.
The *solution* I am looking for is to *write the condition to check **only once***, while being able to **reproduce the original (non-evaluated) condition** and **efficiently evaluate the condition**.

So what are more elegant solutions? Obviously solutions would be easier if Perl had a macro or comparable syntax mechanism that allows transforming the input before compiling or evaluating.

Comment: Could it be done using `Filter::Simple`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `caller` and extract the line of source code that made the assertion?

```
sub assert {
    my ($condition, $msg) = @_;
    return if $condition;
    if (!$msg) {
        my ($pkg, $file, $line) = caller(0);
        open my $fh, "<", $file;
        my @lines = <$fh>;
        close $fh;
        $msg = "$file:$line: " . $lines[$line - 1];
    }
    die "Assertion failed: $msg";
}

assert(2 + 2 == 5);
```

Output:

```
Assertion failed:  assert.pl:14: assert(2 + 2 == 5);
```

If you use `Carp::croak` instead of `die`, Perl will also report stack trace information and identify where the failing assertion was called.

Comment: It seems the usefulness of `caller()` is underestimated ;-)
I like the approach to get the original line, even it may seem a bit inefficient.
However there's a little problem if the condition does not fit into one line; then only the first line is output.

Comment: Probably caller() could be improved: If I print an anonymous subroutine (code ref), I get output showing the line range, not just the first line, like "`CODE(0x24b57e0) -> &main::__ANON__[/tmp/t.pl:13] in /tmp/t.pl:8-13`". But when the call to a subroutine is spread over multiple lines, I just get the number of the first line.

Answer (score 9):

Use [B::Deparse](https://metacpan.org/pod/B::Deparse)?

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use B::Deparse;
my $deparser = B::Deparse->new();

sub assert(&) {
    my($condfunc) = @_;
    my @caller    = caller();
    unless ($condfunc->()) {
        my $src = $deparser->coderef2text($condfunc);
        $src =~ s/^\s*use\s.*$//mg;
        $src =~ s/^\s+(.+?)/$1/mg;
        $src =~ s/(.+?)\s+$/$1/mg;
        $src =~ s/[\r\n]+/ /mg;
        $src =~ s/^\{\s*(.+?)\s*\}$/$1/g;
        $src =~ s/;$//mg;
        die "Assertion failed: $src at $caller[1] line $caller[2].\n";
    }
}

my $var;
assert { 1 };
#assert { 0 };
assert { defined($var) };

exit 0;
```

Test output:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
Assertion failed: defined $var at dummy.pl line 26.
```

Comment: Updated the answer to use syntactic sugar, i.e. `àssert { CONDITION };`.

Comment: If the output were just `defined $var` (the condition that actually failed) instead of the whole block where the assert was executed, It would be acceptable.

Comment: I was able to mangle the output a bit, but still the condition has to be passed as CODE reference. Most of all the condition is optimized, so it may be hard to recognize: `{ 1 < 2 && 7 == 8 }` becomes `Assertion failed: !1 at /tmp/c.pl line 26.`

Answer (score 8):

There are a load of assertion modules on CPAN. These are open source, so it's pretty easy to peek at them and see how they're done.

[Carp::Assert](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carp::Assert) is a low-magic implementation. It has links to a few more complicated assertion modules in its documentation, one of which is my module [PerlX::Assert](https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlX::Assert).

Comment: Actually before asking here, I had looked at a few "solutions", but none of them was really what I'm looking for. Maybe that's the reason why there are so many different solutions. Despite of that I had been thinking about this problem, and I wondered what the most elegant solution might look like (the "learning effect").

Answer (score 3):

One approach to any kind of "assertions" is to use a testing framework.  It isn't as clean-cut as C's `assert` but then it is incomparably more flexible and manageable, while tests can still be freely embedded in code much like `assert` statements are.

A few very simple examples

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Test::More 'no_plan';
Test::More->builder->output('/dev/null');

say "A few examples of tests, scattered around code\n";

like('may be', qr/(?:\w+\s+)?be/, 'regex');
cmp_ok('a', 'eq', 'a ', 'string equality');

my ($x, $y) = (1.7, 13);

cmp_ok($x, '==', $y, '$x == $y');

say "\n'eval' expression in a string so we can see the failing code\n";

my $expr = '$x**2 == $y';
ok(eval $expr, 'Quadratic') || diag explain $expr;  

# ok(eval $expr, $expr);
```

with output

```
A few examples of tests, scattered around code

#   Failed test 'string equality'
#   at assertion.pl line 19.
#          got: 'a'
#     expected: 'a '
#   Failed test '$x == $y'
#   at assertion.pl line 20.
#          got: 1.7
#     expected: 13

'eval' expression in a string so we can see the failing code

#   Failed test 'Quadratic'
#   at assertion.pl line 26.
# $x**2 == $y
# Looks like you failed 3 tests of 4.
```

This is just a scattershot of examples, where the last one answers the question directly.

The module [Test::More](https://perldoc.perl.org/Test/More.html) brings together a number of tools; there are many options in how to use it and how to manipulate output. See [Test::Harness](https://perldoc.perl.org/Test/Harness.html), and [Test::Builder](https://perldoc.perl.org/Test/Builder.html) (used above), and a number of tutorials and SO posts.

I don't know how the above `eval` counts toward "elegant" but it does move you from singular and individually cared for C-style `assert` statements toward a more easily manageable system.

Good assertions are meant and planned as systemic tests and code documentation but by their nature lack formal structure (and so may still end up scattered and ad-hoc). When done this way they come with a framework and can be managed and tuned with many tools, and as a suite.

Comment: Actually I disagree: Assertions serve a documentation purpose and are a part of the code, while test cases are always extern to the code. Most of all, you can't check some internal details with external tests. (Sorry I also did some Eiffel programming where assertions are actually a part of the language. I also did play with JUnit, but still the sources have assertions.)

Comment: @U.Windl Hum? The example above _is_ your program (as indicated by an unrelated `say ...`), and the tests are part of it.  I am not showing a separate (external) test suite, but tests _in your code_.  That'll do _everything_ `assert` does (which I had used and loved for years), and a whole lot more if needed.

Comment: But to summarize regarding the most wanted feature: Any `Test::` cannot reproduce the test condition as a string; instead you'll have to specify a string for each test condition. So basically you substitute `assert($a < $b)` with something like `assert_less($a, $b)`, so that `assert_less()` knows all it needs (operands and operator). Thus it's easy to output `"$a < $b failed"` (but still `$a` and `$b` are already evaluated then).

Comment: @U.Windl Re "_cannot reproduce the test condition as a string_" -- Added an example of that: set up the condition and then use it for both testing and report. It uses `eval` as there is no way to get what you want just so; it's just two clean lines here. This is a complex system that can be stacked any way you want it. (I also edited the answer.)

Comment: @U.Windl In the end it may be abput what you'll, simply, _like_. However, perhaps consider sacrificing some of "elegant" for some of "better." In a modern high level scripting language we don't have to settle for (the good old) C-style assertions. You can go with a tad bit less of that (not quite as clean) but with a lot more of other (tests as a part of a manageable system). Just suggesting an option.